# Store values in dynamically created input fields using laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am trying to store values from dynamically created inputs(rows) to database. But only the last values in the last row is entered in the database.

---

**HTML**

```
 <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 schedule" ng-controller="WorkScheduleCtrl">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <form action="{{Url::to('schedule/addschedule')}}" method="post" name="employeeSchedule" class="form-horizontal form-border" novalidate>
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Work Schedules
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"></div>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th>Shift</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid #ffffff; border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="item in schedules.schedule">
                        <td data-ng-class="{'has-error': employeeSchedule.employee.$invalid && employeeSchedule.employee.$dirty}">
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="employee[]" ng-model="employee" ng-options="employee.employeeName for employee in employees track by employee.usersId" required>
                                <option value="">Select Employee</option>
                            </select>

                            <span class="help-block" ng-if="employeeSchedule.employee.$error.required && employeeSchedule.employee.$dirty">Employee's name is required.
                            </span>

                        </td>

                        <td data-ng-class="{'has-error': employeeSchedule.employeeshift.$invalid && employeeSchedule.employeeshift.$dirty}">
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="employeeshift" ng-model="employeeshift[]" ng-options="employeeshift.title for employeeshift in employeeshifts track by employeeshift.shiftId" required>
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                            </select>

                            <span class="help-block" ng-if="employeeSchedule.employeeshift.$error.required && employeeSchedule.employeeshift.$dirty">Work shift is required.
                            </span>
                        </td>

                        <td data-ng-class="{'has-error': employeeSchedule.location.$invalid && employeeSchedule.location.$dirty}">
                            <select class="form-control input-sm" name="location" ng-model="location[]" ng-options="location.locationName for location in assignedlocation track by location.locationId" required>
                                <option value="">Select</option>
                            </select>

                            <span class="help-block" ng-if="employeeSchedule.location.$error.required && employeeSchedule.location.$dirty">Assigned location is required.
                            </span>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a ng-click="removeItem($index)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete Row"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <a href ng-click="addItem()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm addRowBtn"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>Add row</a>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="text-right">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Save" ng-disabled="!employeeSchedule.$valid" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

---

**ANGULARJS**

```
app.controller('WorkScheduleCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

     /*-----create and remove rows dynamically-----*/
     // assign default values
     $scope.schedules = {
        schedule: [{
            employee: '',
            employeeshift: '',
            location: ''
        }]
    };
    // add row

    $scope.addItem = function() {

      $scope.schedules.schedule.push({
        employee: '',
        employeeshift: '',
        location: ''
      });

    };

    // delete row
    $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        $scope.schedules.schedule.splice(index, 1);
    };
    /*-----./create and remove rows-----*/

   }]);

}]);
```

---

**LARAVEL**

```
public function postAddschedule() {

    $rules = array(
        'employee'      =>  'required',
        'employeeshift' =>  'required',
        'location'      =>  'required'
    );

    // run the validation rules on the inputs from the form
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validator->fails()) {

        return Redirect::to('schedule/addschedule/')
        ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    else {
        $count = count(Input::get('employee'));

        // get data
        $scheduledata = array(
            array(
                'usersId'       =>  Input::get('employee'),
                'shiftId'       =>  Input::get('employeeshift'),
                'locationId'    =>  Input::get('location')
            )
        );

        for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
            DB::table('workschedule')->insert($scheduledata[$i]);
        }

    }// end if/else

}
```

---

---

What should I do to in order to be able to store all values from all the rows into my database?

Comment: All the field names will duplicate for each row. Do a post dump will see.

Comment: How can I rectify this? @charlietfl

Comment: make use of  `$index` in `ng-repeat`  to match whatever looping scheme you create in php. Am a bit confused what you were expecting in php since there doesn't seem to be any loop

Comment: I added the loop that you were wondering about. In the Laravel docs it showed [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#inserts) when inserting multiple records, so I didn't think I needed a loop. But now I have updated my code and added a loop but the error I am getting is **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' **. What am I doing wrong? @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this method. I guess in order to add the data it had to have been specifically assigned.

```
// get data
$usersId        =   Input::get('employee');
$shiftId        =   Input::get('employeeshift');
$locationId =   Input::get('location');

//loop through and save data
for($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {

    $schedule = new WorkSchedule;
    $schedule->usersId      =   $usersId[$i];
    $schedule->shiftId      =   $shiftId[$i];
    $schedule->locationId   =   $locationId[$i];
    $schedule->save();
}
```

Comment: can you please show me the http call in angularjs for this function ?

Comment: Sorry but I did not bother to utilize any `$http.post` since my save button was outside the scope of `ng-repeat`. I sent my data straight to laravel and only used angular to generate the dynamic inputs. Sorry for the extremely late reply. @ziz194